# insert mean of the data into new column

Tags: python

i want to get the mean of falcon and parrot and insert into the new 'Mean' column. the mean value for both falcon should be the same,and the same goes to the parrot.

sry i tried googling this kind of thing, reading the documentation and still cant figure it out :(

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon','Parrot', 'Parrot'], 'Max 
Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})
print (df)

df['Mean'] = df.groupby(['Animal']).mean()

print (df)

Animal  Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0
1  Falcon      370.0
2  Parrot       24.0
3  Parrot       26.0

   Animal  Max Speed  Mean
0  Falcon      380.0   NaN
1  Falcon      370.0   NaN
2  Parrot       24.0   NaN
3  Parrot       26.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my answer:

```py
df2=df.groupby('Animal')["Max Speed"].mean().to_frame(name='Mean').reset_index()
df = df.merge(df2,how='left',on='Animal')
```

Basically you precise on which column you want to group by. Then you select the column you want to perform operations on, here the MaxSpeed. From then we convert the DataFrameGroupby object to a dataframe and specify the name of the new column we are creating (result of groupby operation). The `reset_index()` is not directly usefull here, you can take it off. However in the case of multi index, to ensure that we keep the columns we grouped by on as columns and not index, you need to reset it to have a proper DataFrame

Comment: It is working fine for me, check your variables, you might have a typo or copy/paste mistake

Comment: if u dont mind, can u pls explain the first line, basically what it does

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby('Animal')['Max Speed'].mean()
```

Also might be worth looking at variable naming conventions here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0):

You should merge the dataframe created after the groupby + mean since the number of rows won't match up exactly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot'], 'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})
print(df)

means = df.groupby(['Animal'])['Max Speed'].mean()
print(means)

df = pd.merge(df, means, on='Animal', how='left')

print(df)
```

Comment: Damn fired a sec too late

Comment: this is my first time using groupby and merge,there's an error in your solution

means = df.groupby(['Animal']).mean()
and it changes the column name to max speed x and max speed y